# Writing a large number of files from a long running process?

Tags: optimization, io, output-buffering, filehandle

I have a project which scans a large file (2.5GB) picking out strings which will then be written to some subset of several hundred files.

It would be fastest just to use normal buffered writes but

1. I'm worried about running out of filehandles.
2. I want to be able to watch the progress of the files while they're being written.
3. I would prefer as little loss as possible if the process is interrupted. Incomplete files are still partially useful.

So instead I open in read/write mode, append the new line, and close again.

This was fast enough much of the time but I have found that on certain OSes this behaviour is a severe *pessimization*. Last time I ran it on my Windows 7 netbook I interrupted it after several days!

I can implement some kind of MRU filehandle manager which keeps so many files open and flushes after so many write operations each. But is this overkill?

**This must be a common situation, is there a "best practice", a "pattern"?**

<sup>Current implementation is in Perl and has run on Linux, Solaris, and Windows, netbooks to phat servers. But I'm interested in the general problem: language-independent and cross-platform. I've thought of writing the next version in C or node.js.</sup>

Comment: how do you read the file? line by line? at once? 2.5 is not that large.

Comment: I read it record by record, but that boils down to line by line. It doesn't seem to be the size of the input that slows it down nearly as much as all the flushing of the outputs I think.

Comment: Most similar question I've been able to find so far: [Opening and writing to multiple files in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121838/opening-and-writing-to-multiple-files-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, you can open a lot of files (thousands). You can limit the number of opened handles in a single process with the [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) syscall and the [ulimit](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) shell builtin. You can query them with the `getrlimit` syscall and also using `/proc/self/limits`  (or `/proc/1234/limits` for process of pid 1234). The maximum number of system-wide opened files is thru `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` (on my system, I have 1623114).

So on Linux you could not bother, and open many files at once.

And I would suggest to maintain a [memoized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) [cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29) of opened files, and use them if possible (in a MRU policy). Don't open and close each file too often, only when some limit has been reached... (e.g. when an `open` did fail).

In other words, you could have your own file abstraction (or just a `struct`) which knows the file name, may have an opened `FILE*` (or a null pointer) and keep the current offset, maybe also the last time of opening or writing, then manage a collection of such things in a FIFO discipline (for those having an opened `FILE*`). You certainly want to avoid `close`-ing (and later re-`open`-ing) a file descriptor too often.

You might occasionally (i.e. once a few minutes) call [sync(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sync.2.html), but don't call it too often (certainly not more than once per 10 seconds). If using buffered `FILE`-s don't forget to sometimes `fflush` them. Again, don't do that very often.

Comment: Will the way I'm opening, appending, flushing, and closing the files millions of times be a problem on Linux? I seem to remember reading that a recent optimization in Linux made this bad, I think it was in relation to how how Firefox writes some kinds of files it uses with constant flushes like mine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the memoized cache concept - is this something I can easily implement cross-platform (Solaris and Windows are the other environments). For programming language I'm also open.

Comment: I just added links to wikipedia on memoization & caching